# Is it possible to read allowed values for a datatype property of a class?

Tags: java, rdf, jena, ontology, rdfs

I'm using an ontology in which I created a class named "USER". This class contains a datatype property named "gender". Then I inserted two allowed values for this datatype which are "male" and "female". I wanted to extract these datatype property values in order to insert them into a web page. But I didn't find the right method to do it. I don't even know if it's possible to read these values either.
Here is a part of my ontology. I would be really thankful for any help or suggestions.

```
<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:ID="Gender">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#USER"/>
    <rdfs:range>
      <owl:DataRange>
        <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Resource">
          <rdf:first rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
          >male</rdf:first>
          <rdf:rest rdf:parseType="Resource">
            <rdf:first rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
            >female</rdf:first>
            <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
          </rdf:rest>
        </owl:oneOf>
      </owl:DataRange>
    </rdfs:range>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

ps: I'm not talking about instances, it's just about allowed values for a datatype property of a class :) and I'm using the Jena API.

---

Many thanks for your help, that was really awesome but i still can't get my values :( i also fixed my classe's name and my property's name as well . but i'm always gatting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.NoReaderForLangException: 20 Turtle
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.getReader(RDFReaderFImpl.java:98)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.read(ModelCom.java:215)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntModelImpl.read(OntModelImpl.java:2098)
    at test1.SafwenExample.run(SafwenExample.java:36)
    at test1.SafwenExample.main(SafwenExample.java:31)
Java Result: 1
```

i found 2 casting errors on the recent code so i tried to fix it. here is my code :

```
package test1;

import java.io.StringReader;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class SafwenExample
{
    public static String NS = "http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontology_profile.owl#";

    public static String SOURCE = "@prefix : <http://www.owl-ontologies.com/Ontologyprofile.owl#> .\n" +
            "@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.\n" +
            "@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.\n" +
            "@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.\n" +
            ":User a owl:Class.\n" +
            ":gender a owl:DatatypeProperty ;\n" +
            "  rdfs:domain :User ;\n" +
            "  rdfs:range [\n" +
            "    a owl:DataRange ;\n" +
            "    owl:oneOf ( \"male\"^^xsd:string \"female\"^^xsd:string )\n" +
            "].";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new SafwenExample().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
        m.read( new StringReader( SOURCE ), null, "Turtle" );

        OntProperty gender = m.getOntProperty( NS + "gender" );

        DataRange genderRange = (DataRange) gender.getRange().as( DataRange.class );
        for (ExtendedIterator i = genderRange.listOneOf(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Literal l = (Literal) i.next();
            System.out.println( "DataRange has value " + l.getLexicalForm() +
                                " with datatype: " + l.getDatatype() );
        }
    }
}
```

Ps: many thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Which version of Java and Jena are you running? I notice that you changed the generics iterator `ExtendedIterator<Literal> i` to `ExtendedIterator i`, which suggests a *very* old version of Java. And if your Jena installation does not recognise `Turtle` as an input syntax, it must be very old indeed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using Jena's [Ontology API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/index.html):

```
package example;

import java.io.StringReader;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class SafwenExample
{
    public static String NS = "http://example.com/example#";

    public static String SOURCE = "@prefix : <http://example.com/example#> .\n" +
            "@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.\n" +
            "@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.\n" +
            "@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.\n" +
            ":User a owl:Class.\n" +
            ":gender a owl:DatatypeProperty ;\n" +
            "  rdfs:domain :User ;\n" +
            "  rdfs:range [\n" +
            "    a owl:DataRange ;\n" +
            "    owl:oneOf ( \"male\"^^xsd:string \"female\"^^xsd:string )\n" +
            "].";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        new SafwenExample().run();
    }

    public void run() {
        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
        m.read( new StringReader( SOURCE ), null, "Turtle" );

        OntProperty gender = m.getOntProperty( NS + "gender" );

        DataRange genderRange = gender.getRange().as( DataRange.class );
        for (ExtendedIterator<Literal> i = genderRange.listOneOf(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            Literal l = i.next();
            System.out.println( "DataRange has value " + l.getLexicalForm() +
                                " with datatype: " + l.getDatatype() );
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I fixed your names: class `User` (leading upper case, then camel case), property `gender` (leading lowercase).

Comment: i'm alway wating for your advices :)

Comment: Comment above. This code runs without change using JDK 1.7.0 and version 2.10.0 of Jena.

Comment: Please is there any other library i need to use ? i already installed JDK1.7.0 and jena 2.4.6 as i had old ones but still got an error. thnaks

Comment: Version 2.4.6 is too old. Use the current version, 2.10.0.

Comment: i'm still gettion the following error:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.util.Metadata.<clinit>(Metadata.java:39)
 at com.hp.hpl.jena.JenaRuntime.<clinit>(JenaRuntime.java:34) shouldn't i add slf4j library to my project's libs?

Comment: You should add all of the `.jar` files from the Jena distribution you are using to your project's classpath. Alternatively use maven, which will take care of all of the dependencies for you.

Comment: I fixed my libraries, the error changed but i'm still getting the following message:"No appenders found for logger" and "Please configure log4j properly" could it be that i'm puttin the wrong uri's ? i found and answer in this web-page[http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig]  but i still don't know how to fix it.Thank you Lan :)

Comment: thank's lan it's working :) i have inserted wrong uri's. sorry i heave less than 15 reputation :(

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working. Please accept the answer by clicking on the arrow button by the question, to tell other users of the site that your question has been resolved.